# How to cast an array as NSMutableArray to be able to use removeObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have an array of users which I'm trying to cast as `NSMutableArray` to be able to use `removeObjectAtIndex`, but it doesn't work.
 I get either the error `Cast from '[ModelUser]?' to unrelated type 'NSMutableArray' always fails` if I try to cast it, or `'[ModelUser]' does not have a member named 'removeObjectAtIndex'` if I don't.

So how could I remove an object from my array in this code?

```
query.friend(friendId, command: command, completion: { (result:Bool) -> () in
if result {
   self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
   if let friendR = self.friendRequests as? NSMutableArray{
        friendR.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
   }
   println("Friendship deleted")
})
```

Comment: is your previous array is NSArray and you are converting into nsmutable?

Comment: I'm not sure, I declare it like this: `var friendRequests: [ModelUser]?`

Comment: please post the ModelUser class

Comment: BTW is this your avator ^-^ ? You looks dangerous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn an `NSArray` into an `NSMutableArray` simply by casting it - they are different classes.  To get a mutable array from an `NSArray` you can invoke the `mutableCopy` method on the NSArray.

However, in your case the array is a Swift array, so it is already mutable.

You need to use `removeAtIndex` not `removeObjectAtIndex` to remove an object from a Swift array -

```
query.friend(friendId, command: command, completion: { (result:Bool) -> () in
if result {
   self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
   if self.friendRequests != nil {
        self.friendRequests!.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
   }
   println("Friendship deleted")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this **However, in your case the array is a Swift array, so it is already mutable.** ... I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing a type casting only. You need to make `friendR` mutable to delete and add any object.

```
if let friendR = self.friendRequests.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableArray{
    friendR.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}
```

`mutableCopy()` and a new Instance of `NSMutableArray` would work.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the following code to directly cast for example NSMutableArray to [YourType]

```
if var friendR = self.friendRequests as? AnyObject as? [ModelUser] {
    // your swift array handling code here
}
```

I used `var` keyword to enable future `friendR` mutations

Answer (score -1):

You should just initialize your `self.friendRequests` as an NSMutableArray from the beginning